# PHPThumb generates a black background on transparent PDFS

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, phpthumb

Within the last few months our generated thumbnails have been replacing transparent PDF areas with just a black area.

EX: [Generated Image](http://media.tmgvelocity.com/phpThumb.php?src=/velocity/pdfs/proofs/235000033_14903781942959proof.pdf&q=85&w=400)

Has anyone ran into an issue with this? Not sure if this is a phpthumb or an imagemagic issue. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The first thing I notice is the file type you have linked to is a jpg which does not support transparency.